# How to concatenate the names of every object in $tags?

Tags: php, laravel

When I upload an image, there's a field which takes tags in this format:

```
tag1,tag2,tag3
```

then I explode those tags on every comma and insert every separate tag in the database. Now I am trying to do the reverse thing, get all tags in $tags and then concatenate $tag->name with a comma for every tag. For example:

After getting my tags with:

```
$tags = Tag::whereHas('images', function($q) use ($id) {
    return $q->where('taggable_id', $id);
})->get();
```

$tags have 2 tags with the following names, Summer and Winter. I am trying to somehow get a string that is "Summer,Winter". I'm not exactly sure how to do that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get $tags and it is `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` instance you cane use this code

```
$tagConcateNames = $tags->implode('name', ',')
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example which you need.

```
$tags = Tag::whereHas('images', function($q) use ($id) {
    return $q->where('taggable_id', $id);
})->selectRaw("GROUP_CONCAT(name) as group_names")->get();
```

Sometimes we need to use Raw queries to perform actions on data. Try this. I think this will give you result as you required.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what to do with the result from that. It returns "[{"GROUP_CONCAT(name)":"tag1,tag2"}]"

Comment: @Bobimaru I updated my answer. if that will not provide you exact answer then provide me what response you want from this. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have 2 tags in my tags table - tag1 and tag2. My query returns those 2 tags. If I were to loop through tags and display $tag->name I would get tag1 and tag2. Now I need to somehow concatenate the first tag->name to the second tag->name so that in the end I am returned a string "tag1,tag2". Of course this has to work with any number of tags in the $tags variable.